# Java | Sorting ArrayList by element's field

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

[Team Class](http://pastebin.com/UHegBFrP)

[ScoreBoard Class](http://pastebin.com/cauebcw8)

Hi, So I'm creating a tournament scoreboard GUI which takes a list of teams with the following fields:

```
Name
Wins
Point Spread
Time
Losses
Ties

    getMainElo()    <--- Isn't an instance
    getTieElo()     <--- Isn't an instance
```

With this, I add the Teams to an ArrayList in the ScoreBoard Class and my next move is to sort them by their

```
MainElo Team.getMainElo()
```

and then

```
TieElo Team.getTieElo()                   (If MainElo is the ==)
```

After they are sorted, I want to copy that sorted array into a new Array in the ScoreBoard class so It can be later used to print to the GUI.

I have been trying to use the Comparable interface along with comparators but I cannot for the life of me get anything to work.

Comment: Could you post your attempts? You might be close, but without code you'll never know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by attempts. I included my source for the Team and ScoreBoard classes in the above. I get NullPointers from that.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the links -- that's why you should include your code in your question if possible. Mentioning NPEs from the start would have been helpful too. Where do you get those?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using java.util.Collections.sort(Collection, Comparator) if you cant use a properly treeset. Collections also offers methods for a sorted collection copy.

Comment: I've tried doing so with a custom Comparator but I have not had any success. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when I do so.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this helps.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Team>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
        if(o1.getMainElo().equals(o2.getMainElo())){
            return o1.getTieElo().compareTo(o2.getTieElo());
        }
        return o1.getMainElo().compareTo(o2.getMainElo());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed all fields in the Team class are static, which means they will be shared by all instances of this class.

You need to make them instance variables and then you should be able to sort using a Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to pass a condition for equallity.

```
public int compareTo(Team otherTeam) {
    return this.getMainElo() == otherTeam.getMainElo() ? 
        this.getTieElo() - otherTeam.getTieElo()
        : this.getMainElo() - otherTeam.getMainElo();      
}
```